# Delphi: Component Build - Associate TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, components, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I'm building a new component and I would like to add one property where to associate a `TVirtualStringTree` object.

In the bellow picture I indicate and example from a `TLabel` object with the property `FocusControl` associated to a `TEdit`

[image]

If I do like this:

```
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FVirtualStringTree: TVirtualStringTree;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property VirtualStringTree: TVirtualStringTree read FVirtualStringTree write FVirtualStringTree;
  end;
```

I get an error like this: "Cannot load package .... It contains unit VirtualTrees.WorkerThread, which is also contained in package VirtualTreesR22.

Please an advise about how can I create this type of associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the association, the problem is that you (indirectly) include code from `TVirtualStringTree` into the package, and another installed package already has that same unit.

Since that other package is apparently the runtime package for `TVirtualStringTree`, you should simply reference that package from your package. Then it will not try to incorporate the unit, it will reference it from `VirtualTreesR` instead. This way, you avoid the conflict and all should be well:

```
package Bla;

  ...

requires
  VirtualTreesR,
  vcl,
  etc....
```

Comment: E2202 Required package `VirtualTreesR22` not found! In the *.pas file I'm force to use `VirtualTrees` otherwise `TVirtualStringTree` is not recognized. Should I used another descendent?

Comment: Ok, It works with `VirtualTreesR` instead! Thanks Rudy.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with association of TFDConnection. Where can be found this information in fact?

Comment: Probably that can be found in a FireDac package. I don't know which.